# || (or) equivalent in C/++ preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor-directive

I want to use or in a preprocessor `#ifdef` directive. I've tried using the `||` operator but it hasn't worked. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

```
#if defined(SOMETHIG1) || defined(SOMETHING2)
/* .... */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`#ifdef COND` is short for `#if defined(COND)`. It has no way to combine conditions.

But, you don't need to use `#ifdef`! If you write it out in full, you can make use of all the operators you need:

```
#if defined(COND1) || defined(COND2)
```